# Time series of cluster analysis spatiotemporal python

Tags: python, k-means, dtw

I want to cluster patterns based on three meteorological fields. Each field has the shape 31, 137, 181 (31 timesteps, 137 latitudes, 181 longitudes) and I want a spatial maps of clusters for each timestep. Given the labels in a generic kmeans clustering approach do not have a meaning and do not allow 'tracking' of clusters over time, I tried using `tslearn.clustering` in python, but I'm not sure about how to structure my data? This is the example that is working for me

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from tslearn.clustering import TimeSeriesKMeans

# Load the data
ds_var1 = xr.open_dataset(var1).var1
ds_var2 = xr.open_dataset(var2).var2
ds_var3 = xr.open_dataset(var3).var3

# Stack
X = np.stack((ds_msl.values.flatten(),
              ds_10u.values.flatten(), 
              ds_10v.values.flatten()), 
              axis=1)

X = X.reshape(-1, 3, 1) ###??

# Cluster the data using time-series k-means
n_clusters = 8
km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, 
                      metric="euclidean", 
                      verbose=0, 
                      max_iter=5, 
                      n_init=5, 
                      random_state=0)

labels = km.fit_predict(X)

# Reshape the cluster labels to match the original data shape
labels = labels.reshape(ds_var1.shape)
```

As far as I understood the shape of `X` is meant to be number_of_samples, number_of_frames, features? But it is not obvious to me how this applies to my problem. `X = X.reshape(-1, 3, 1) (X.shape = (768707, 3, 1))` produces output, but I don't know whether this is actually the correct structure of the data/ do I need to assume a completely different shape (e.g. `X = X.reshape(-1, 3)` which also works)? I also could not find it in the documentation. Can anyone help me figure this out?